# Error when starting aca-py agent with the help of seed parameter

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-indy, decentralized-identity, indy-node, decentralized-identifiers

I am trying to start the aca-py agent with the command :-

aca-py start --wallet-name user3 --wallet-key user3 --wallet-type indy --genesis-file /<PATH_TO_GENESIS_FILE>/docker_pool_transactions_genesis --ledger-pool-name local_pool --inbound-transport http 127.0.0.1 8001 --admin 127.0.0.1 9001 --endpoint http://127.0.0.1:8001 --outbound-transport http --log-level DEBUG --admin-insecure-mode --seed 00000000000000000000000000000001

But it is giving me the following error :-
aries_cloudagent.config.base.ConfigError: Ledger rejected transaction request: client request invalid: could not authenticate, verkey for 4cLztgZYocjqTdAZM93t27 cannot be found

Why is this issue coming and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Is because you are spinning up with a public DID. For this reason is checking if the Verkey linked to the DID (seed) is on the ledger, so before spinning up the aca-py you have to publish the DID in the ledger. So, go to the VON network manage page (http://localhost:9000) and publish the DID in " Authenticate a New DID" and copy the seed in the first textbox and publish the DID.
You should now see a new record in the ledger of type NYM with the VerKey linked to the NYM (aka DID)
[image: Indy VON Page]